# Suspended hyphen example

Tags: hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

As far as I've seen, it seems like whether or not one should use suspended hyphens is determined on a mostly ad-hoc basis. So, I was wondering if someone could give me advice on whether or not the following usage is OK:

> Our system uses four triaxial accelerometers, so each outputs an x-, y-, and z-acceleration.

Comment: How do you mean, "a mostly ad-hoc basis"? There's a very clear and simple rule.

Comment: I wouldn't use these suspended hyphens, but I would use italics for the three variable names (but not for "acceleration").

Comment: There is no rule in English for this.  You should follow the conventions established for your particular science,

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I believe that the usage in this example is appropriate, I would also like to play devil's advocate in questioning whether the usage is even required.

In this example, the variations of acceleration direction could be restated as follows

> Our system uses four triaxial accelerometers, so each outputs a 3-dimensional vector in Cartesian coordinate space.

Given that I don't know the context of the example, I am unsure whether the more technical details are correct, but I believe the concept is correct.